# Documents for Standard Visitor Visa UK

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have read somewhere in the uk government web-page that every document that I send with my application for visa should be original and not a copy. But there is a problem because there are some documents that I cannot find as originals. My trip to England is going to be sponsored from my cousin that lives in england and is a british citizen so the embassy needs a bank statement from my sponsor. As I said he lives in england is it a problem if he sends me the bank statement by email (will this be called a copy from uk visa officer) [image: ..]?

Comment: Your cousin can snail-mail an original statement to you, and you can then include the original in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Now some banks may no longer send paper bank statement to customer, so if the original of your brother's bank statement is electronic (e.g. PDF), I believe it's perfectly fine to have him email the document to you and print it out. And if there's indeed an original hard copy that your brother own, as @DavidSupportsMonica mentioned have him send you the physical copy.